# Enterprise MVC Application Project Setup With Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I was looking at [this](http://blog.keithpatton.com/2009/05/30/Entity+Framework+POCO+Repository+Using+Visual+Studio+2010+Net+40+Beta+1.aspx) site which shows a pseudo project setup for entity framework.  I know this article does not use MVC but it did get me thinking.  Would you guys have your "model" tier to include all of the Entity Framework references, entities, business rules, repository facade, interfaces, buddy classes for validation, and the design model too?  Feels a bit bloated.  Would you extract any of that to an "Infastructure" tier?

Comment: So I want to extract my model layer out to an entityframework library and an interfaces library (all under the model namespace).  But!  My entities (which are used in the interfaces) are located in my EF implementation library and I can't have both libs reference each other (circular reference).  That is my issue!

Comment: Combine the libraries, unless you are dropping in physical replacements, just combine them. http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/09/30/separate-assemblies-loose-coupling.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My "interfacing the model" moments of granduer are on hold for right now.  Here is [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429239/is-it-possible-to-setup-an-interface-library-for-a-dal-using-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Only if I needed additional decoupling.  There is a cost for creating new interfaces to establish new tiers.

If by tier you mean another machine, I certainly don't think you need that.

Within the model "tier" you can always provide additional namespaces, etc. to improve organization.

Comment: By tier I meant logical tier so it would be through namespaces