# Is It Possible To Setup An Interface Library For A DAL Using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a model library (namespace `Test.App.Model.EF`) with the Entity Framework implementation in it.  This has all of the entities provided in the EF designer for me which I want to use.  Within this `Model.EF` implementation, I have several repository classes.  I want to create interfaces for these classes and place them in a seperate interface library (`Test.App.Model.Interface`).  So I do so, obviously the implementation library needs a reference the interfaces.  BUT, I notice that the interfaces need to know about the objects in the EF designer (since I want to reuse them).  I can't create a reference from the interface library to the ef implementation because then I'll have a circular reference.

So, as I write this, I'm coming to the conclusion that I'll probably need a `Test.App.Entities.EF` that has the Entity Framework "created" entities.  That way my interfaces lib could reference without having to know about the `Model.EF`.

Does that sound like the way to go?

Comment: Why are you creating interfaces for the EF objects? I could understand creating interface's for the repositories, so that you could have a testable repository which wasn't connected to the database. If you could explain this it might help answering your question?

Comment: Have you considered using DTOs?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Comment: I'm not interested in creating an interface for the entities, it is just for the repositories. The problem is that the entities and the repositories live in the same library. I can't abstract out the repositories in a sep library when the entities are in that same library so it looks like I'll have to seperate them. I just found it weird to have two Entity framework implementation libraries (for repository and entities) but it looks like I'll need to.

Comment: DTO's would help but I really didn't want the overhead for this project.  Thanks for the offer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after much wrestling with this, I found the buzz term that describes the situation.  What I'm looking for here is called ["Persistence Ignorance"](http://dddstepbystep.com/wikis/ddd/persistence-ignorance.aspx).  This is what would make what I described in my thread happen.  Well the Entity Framework that we use (not 4.0) does not support this yet (unless you go homegrown like done [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jkowalski/archive/2008/09/09/persistence-ignorance-poco-adapter-for-entity-framework-v1.aspx)).

With having that said, EF 4.0 will have this feature but from what I understand, it's coupled with .NET 4.0 (why it's called EF 4.0 in the first place) and that's not going on our production servers anytime soon.  Since we've decided to go with this technology, our repository abstraction to interfaces will be placed on hold until upgrading to 4.0 is a viable option.

Let this be a caveat for those seeking the same information.  Please also let me know if this sounds incorrect (because I would love to make this happen sooner then later but I don't want my team jumping through hoops when a later implementation will remedy the issue).  Thanks all!

Comment: Not sure if this is possible at the time of your posting: You also have the option of placing all your Entities in a separate library from Model.EF and Model.Interfaces, say Model.Entities. Your DataContext can then be given an entity: `MyContext.GetTable<TEntity>()`.